# Why SmartScreen Filter blocks all my executables?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, digital-signature

I have several `WinForm` tools now. I publish them on an internal website. So my issue is that in case `SmartScreen` filter is turned on in IE then the users can't download them. They get "blocked" error message. If it's turned off then everything is fine, so it is `SmartScreen` for sure.

All the files are signed by `Verisign` certificates and all the file details are filled.

So the question: Ho can you make SmartScreen to trust your files, or how can you bypass it without making all the users turning it off?

Comment: Put the site where you host your applications in a trusted intranet zone, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538925/how-can-i-work-around-smartscreen-filter-without-spending-a-boatload-of-money

Comment: I already did that, but no go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop my installer from triggering Windows 10's “This app has been blocked for your protection” error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414291/how-can-i-stop-my-installer-from-triggering-windows-10s-this-app-has-been-bloc).

Comment: Look in to ClickOnce

Comment: @Ben ClickOnce is disabled and since I need the manifest file to force the tool to be ran as admin I can' lt enable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is an internal company tool, you should ask the company's systems administrators to deploy it for you.

- It can be deployed using Group Policy, Systems Management Server or whatever management system they use.
- Systems administrators have the ability to enable ClickOnce, then you can deploy it using ClickOnce.
- No doubt they have other methods they use for other internal tools.

But the short answer is: *You should not be trying to circumvent the protections that your company has put in place.*

Instead, talk to them and they will help you find a way to get it done.

Comment: I don't want to circumvent, but to get SmartScreen reputation.

Comment: 1) It's an internal tool. SmartScreen reputation is for publicly available software. 2) Have you told your systems administrators? They probably have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Smartscreen creates problems when you are trying to send binary files.SmartScreen responds by stating that the file is not commonly downloaded and can therefore install harmful files on your system. A common distribution trick to bypass SmartScreen warnings is to pack the installation package (Setup.exe) into ZIP-archive and distribute it that way.