# How to add certified publisher in desktop application using advance installer

Tags: windows-installer, desktop-application, code-signing-certificate, advanced-installer

I have created installer of `.net` desktop application using advanced installer. The problem is that the publisher during installation is unknown I have created test certificate which works fine on same machine but If I want to install it on other machine its publisher becomes unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Trusted Root Certificates***: **`Not my expertise`** (just so that is clear), but you can't use a **self-issued certificate** for public release of an installer (maybe you can use a self-signed certificate internally in your company if you get it onto all boxes). The certificate must be available on the system you install on. I believe what you need is a proper [code signing certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Code_signing_certificate) issued by a **trusted root authority**: **[How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018)**. All Windows installations should have a number of root certificates that are trusted outright, issued by trustworthy organizations. **`You need to sign your setup with a certificate that is issued by such a trusted organization`**. Prices wary.

***EV Code-Signing Certificate***: It seems like one needs an [**`EV code-signing certificate`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) these days to deal with the [**`SmartScreen feature`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018) in Windows - which is "trust based". These certificates apparently "buy you trust". Interesting concept... Root Certificates: [Microsoft Trusted Root Certificate Program - Portal](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33315.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-portal.aspx) ([2018](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51151.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants-as-of-january-30-2018.aspx)).

---

***Further Information***: Please do check previous answer for more links (don't want a dual source problem):

- [How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018) (same link as above).
- [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer/51209972#51209972)
- [How to avoid the "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-fro)