# How to prevent "Microsoft defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognised app" warning for my own python based app

Tags: security, windows-defender

I  developed a python based application for windows and I created a setup exe for installation into Program Files (x86) folder via inno setup tool. My problem is whenever I execute my setup.exe file on another windows device which was downloaded from my website by chrome, SmartScreen shows "Microsoft defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognised app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk" warning.
I found 2 methods to bypass the warning:
(reference: [How to avoid the "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-fro))

1- Click "Run anyway" button-> I really do not want to give my users an impression that my application is an unreliable one. So therefore this option is not ok for me and I want to get rid of this warning from the beginning

2-Buying EV or OV signing certificate -> I do not want to spend any money at the beginning of my startup project.

So the only solution which I found and makes sense is "submitting my app for malware for malware analyses":
I tried to do that which following link and steps:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission ->clicking Software developer button -> then under file download button
I saw following note:
"Submit only the specific files you want analyzed. Submitting an installer package or an archive with a large number of files may delay the analysis and cause your submission to be deprioritized"
So it means that it is also not the right way to get rid of this warning message.

Does anyone any other idea?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you've built a Python app, why does it need a setup/installer at all?

Comment: Regardless, SmartScreen is going to be heuristically evaluating your executable's trustworthiness. If you don't have a signing certificate, you're basically at the mercy of its false positives. I would recommend moving to remove the installation dependency entirely if possible - Python code is more than capable of being run on its own, uncompiled, and in a cross-platform way to boot. Compiling an interpreted language brings these types of risks and is usually not the right answer.

Comment: Hi espew, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I want keep my setup.exe because of 2 reasons:
1-It looks more professional
2-the app ins not standalone app. It means that  my exe is inside a folder with other libraries. 

But if I could not find a proper solution, then I will consider your suggestion.  Thanks