# How to whitelist a UNC from Windows Defender SmartScreen by GPO?

Tags: c#, security, clickonce, gpo, windows-defender

I have some C# ClickOnce applications distributed via our intranet UNC.  Recently, a new organization level GPO has been pushed down removing the "Run Anyway" button.  I need a method of adding the application to the trusted list within windows defender.

App is installed/updated from UNC:
\\Org\InternalApplications\[Application]\setup.exe

GPO To Disable "Run Anyway" Button on Windows Smart Defender:
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Defender SmartScreen\Explorer\Configure Windows Defender SmartScreen
->Enabled, Warn and prevent bypass

Note: Applications are signed via an organization code-sign token listed in all computer's trusted root certification authorities.  Adding the code-sign token's certificate directly to the Personal Certificate store did not resolve the issue.

---

Similar Question Links:
Windows Store: (WACK)
[How to pass the smart screen on Win8 when install a signed application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311203/how-to-pass-the-smart-screen-on-win8-when-install-a-signed-application)
EV Certificate: [How can I stop my installer from triggering Windows 10's "This app has been blocked for your protection" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414291/how-can-i-stop-my-installer-from-triggering-windows-10s-this-app-has-been-bloc)

Comment: I know this has been an eternity, but did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Emilio 'fraid not.